# Does a Tunisian wife of a Brit need a visa to visit the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, family, tunisian-citizens

I am a British Citizen living in Tunisia (so are my two daughters). My wife is a Tunisian Citizen.

We are planning to visit the UK for a holiday. Does my wife needs a Visa and which kind?
If so, how do I apply.

Comment: Advise her to run her information through [Check if you need a UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa), and ask if the result is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your wife needs a visa.  For a holiday, the proper visa is the [standard visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa).  The fact that she is married to a British citizen or the mother of British citizens does not exempt her from the visa requirement.